# Can't access Developer Tools on Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-elcapitan, developer-tools

I am running El Capitan on my 2011 MacBook pro. I can't open the developer tools on Google Chrome. I click the button and nothing happens. I am running Chrome version Version 47.0.2526.80 (64-bit). I've reinstalled Google Chrome, restarted my computer, and reset mac software by starting up while holding "command + option + p + r" but i still can't access it...
What should I do?

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1466649